# Foreach loop: if string equals previous string

Tags: php

So, I am creating a history of changes page from database that has one row for each update. I need to represent only values that have changed. I represent those values in foreach loop (to make it more simple I reduced it to 1 value: work stations):

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT * FROM user_customers_history
");

$sth->execute();

foreach ($sth as $key => $row) {

$crm_workstations = $row['crm_workstations'];

if (($crm_workstations > 0) && ($crm_workstations != $crm_workstations)){

        echo '<br/><br/>' . $crm_workstations;

}
```

I defined $key as an index, but I don't know how to use it. I know that I want to represent it this way: for each index check if the value is equal to previous index value. If they are not equal, show it.

Comment: You need to "fetch" first.

Comment: try posting your full code....not too sure what you are trying to do here.  Are you trying to compare the DB values against user input values?

Comment: Thank you @Fred-ii- , like this: `$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` ?

Comment: Dear @Austin I am trying to compare database values and `echo` only the ones that are different from the older ones.

Comment: something to that effect, yes.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Fred-ii-

Comment: you're welcome Lukas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a previous value for your variable to compare with the current one:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT * FROM user_customers_history
");

$sth->execute();

$prev_workstations = '';

while ($row = $sth->fetch()) { 

    $crm_workstations = $row['crm_workstations'];
    if (($crm_workstations > 0) && ($crm_workstations != $prev_workstations)){

        $prev_workstations = $crm_workstations;
        echo '<br/><br/>' . $crm_workstations;

    }  
}
```

They ask me to edit more then 6 characters I needed to write somthing :D